# spinner value is dynamically change depends upon database

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

hi i have to developed one app..here i have to updated my spinner value in my mysql database..

for eg:[image: status]....here i have to run the app first time always display Q only..here i have to update the status Q to C after i have to run the app means automatically displayed the status C....how can i develop this.why always displayed Q...how can i manage the code here.
here i have used below code.

```
 private void createSpinnerDropDown() {

    //get reference to the spinner from the XML layout
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    //Array list of animals to display in the spinner
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("Q");
    list.add("P");
    list.add("F");
    list.add("I");
    list.add("C");

    //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    //set the view for the Drop down list
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //set the ArrayAdapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //attach the listener to the spinner
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

}
```

how can i develop this.

Comment: i'm not clear you want to save selected item to DB or want to show saved item in DB to Spinner ??

Comment: my database have status is C means i wish to display my spinner also display C...but in my code Q only displayed on spinner always...

Comment: here i have to run the app first time always display Q on my spinner box..here i have to update the status Q to C after i have to run the app means automatically displayed the status C....how can i develop this.why always displayed Q...how can i manage the code here.

Comment: your spinner items (Q,P,F,I,C ) are static ??

Comment: my database have C means this C only displayed on my Console window automatically

Comment: check my ans if it helps for you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16356/discussion-between-krishnaveni-and-aafaq)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(list.contains(DATABASE.FETCH()))
   spinner.setSelection(list.indexOf(DATABASE.FETCH()));
```

the DATABASE.FETCH() is your method of fetching the data (C) from the database.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know it will exactly you want .how i managed this,instead of save the selected item get only the selectedItemPosition

```
int selectedIndex = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

and when you want to set the spinner item from data base, just fetch the index, let say

```
int SavedIndex = FetchSavedSpinnerIndex();
```

now set your spinner's item as

```
spinner.setSelection(SavedIndex);
```